# First child does not work with my selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

my js

```
$('dd:first-child', 'dd:first-child(2)').remove();
```

consider my markup is like this

```
<dd>
<br>
<br?
</dd>
```

why it doesn't work?

Comment: `first-child(2)` is not a function

Comment: it's not `first-child` that you need, it is `nth-child()`! `first-child` only returns the first matched element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `first-child(2)` is not a function so it will give an error.
It should be:

```
$('dd:first-child, dd:eq(1)').remove();
```

or

```
$('dd:eq(0), dd:eq(1)').remove();
```

or

```
$('dd:nth-child(1), dd:nth-child(2)').remove();
```

This might also work:

```
$('dd:lt(2)').remove();
```

[lt selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

[Fiddle for `lt(2)`](http://jsfiddle.net/h12qo3oe/)

Edit:

To delete the `<br>` you can do:

```
$('dd br:lt(2)').remove();
```

Comment: I want to remove <br> actually

Comment: You want to delete both of them?

Comment: Did you really intend to pass two arguments to jQuery?