# nth-child doesn't work in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<dd>
    <br>
    <br>
</dd>
```

how to remove above `<br>` ? I tried

```
$('dd:nth-child(1)', 'dd:nth-child(2)').remove();
```

as you can see the 
 is still there:
http://jsfiddle.net/h12qo3oe/2/

Comment: You could do this may be `$('dd').eq(1).remove();`

Comment: What is your intention? What do you want to achieve? Why does this question look familiar? Did you mean `$('dd:nth-child(1), dd:nth-child(2)').remove();`?

Comment: Didn't you [ask this already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308818/first-child-does-not-work-with-my-selector)?

Comment: The second argument passed to `jQuery` is the **context** in which the first argument is evaluated. Please **read the documentation** (http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context). That's better than arbitrarily trying things.

Answer (score 2):

What you're currently doing with your jQuery selector is actually [specifying a namespace/context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) for selecting an element.
  `$('selector', 'place-to-look')`.

You're telling jQuery to look for `selector` as a child of the context element `place-to-look`, which, in this case, you're looking for a `<dd>` located under another `<dd>` that's second in the outer list.

... which doesn't exist! (Oh no!)

I'm sure others will give you the answer of 'syntax error', but I thought you might like to know what you're doing as opposed to selecting in the same set of quotes like so: `$('dd:nth-child(1), dd:nth-child(2)')`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery accepts [second argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2672041/1520671) as context, so in your statement `dd:nth-child(2)` is considered as context and `dd:nth-child(1)` is searched in that context.

If you're trying to remove `br`s. For that you can use this

```
$('dd').find('br').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it this way: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h12qo3oe/3/)**

```
$('dd').children('br').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove both `br`, This will work here

```
$('dd br:nth-child(1), dd br:nth-child(2)').remove();
```

There were two problems in your code.

**1)** You were giving two selectors as two parameters in `$`. So wrapping them in quotes `''` makes a single parameter.

**2)** `$('dd:nth-child(1)'` will select first `dd` so you should say `$('dd br:nth-child(1)'`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/h12qo3oe/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on what people are saying:

The reason your query isn't working is because [jQuery's multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) only takes a single parameter. It's a simple fix, just change

```
$('dd:nth-child(1)', 'dd:nth-child(2)').remove();
```

to

```
$('dd:nth-child(1), dd:nth-child(2)').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I suggest you to use the correct jQuery multi elements selector:

```
$("element1, element2")
```

In your case you just need to think at the "nth-child" as a selector in an array (arr[x]).
In your code you're just selecting the second dd element in your document. For removing only the first "br" tag I would proceed as following:

```
$("dd br:nth-child(1)").remove();
```

Or, better, following the latest jQuery suggestion about navigating the DOM:

```
$("dd").find("br").get(0).remove();
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to remove the `br`'s; the first and second children of `dd`. You want the psuedo selector `:nth-child` to apply to `br` not `dd`; `br`'s are the children.

Secondly, as @Morklympious has clearly explained, the second argument in `$('sel', 'context')` is the context of your search:

```
$('dd > br').filter(':nth-child(1),:nth-child(2)').remove(); //removes first two children br of dd

$('dd > br:lt(2)').remove(); //same

$('dd > br').remove(); // removes all br children of dd
```